# How to use my iMac 27" with new Mac pro

Tags: safari

I currently have a iMac (27-inch, Late 2009, Intel Core 2 Duo) which I would like to use as display for a new Mac Pro. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US#4

1. Connect the Mac Pro to the iMac with a Thunderbolt or Mini DisplayPort cable.
2. Press `Command-F2` on the iMac's keyboard (or `Command-Fn-F2` if this doesn't work).